# CakePHP: How to find columns ordered by number of related models?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0, relation

i hope someone is able to help me. i have two tables websites and likes. each website has likes. i can't figure out how i can get all websites ordered by the number of its likes. this sounds pretty basic to me but i failed to find a solution...

something like the following is what i tried last (actsas containable in model is available):

```
$this->paginate = array('contain' => array(
    'Like' => array(
         'order' => array('count(Like.id) DESC')
    )
));
$this->set('websites', $this->paginate());
```

could someone help me please?

cheers.
Andreas

// UPDATE
i found a solution. i use now the countercache. for those who are interested should [counterCache - Cache your count()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) here and thats my code

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'order' => array('like_count' => 'desc'),
    'limit' => 15
);
$this->set('websites', $this->paginate());
```

Comment: $this->paginate() and $this->paginate are DEPRECATED. You should use $this->Paginator->settings and $this->Paginator->paginate() now.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You should post it as an answer, and accept that answer (ie, answer your own question). That makes it more clear for future users who might have the same problem.

Comment: @burzum They might just as well be undeprecated again soon (as per discussion on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cakephp-core/5o8M9x0qH7c ). The main part to make it work is to either use the component way completely, or use the controller way completely, not to mix those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution. i use now the countercache. for those who are interested should read [counterCache - Cache your count()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) here and thats my code

```
$this->paginate = array(
     'order' => array('like_count' => 'desc'),
     'limit' => 15
);
$this->set('websites', $this->paginate());
```